# DISTINCT LIKE query very slow even with index

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have the following query on SQL Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Doctor 
FROM Table 
WHERE (Doctor LIKE 'dr[.,][ !^]ab%' 
       OR Doctor LIKE 'dr[., !^]ab%' 
       OR Doctor LIKE 'dr[., !^] _ ab%' 
       OR Doctor LIKE 'mr[.,][ !^]ab%' 
       OR Doctor LIKE 'mr[., !^]ab%' 
       OR Doctor LIKE 'mr[., !^] _ ab%' 
       OR Doctor LIKE 'ms[.,][ !^]ab%' 
       OR Doctor LIKE 'ms[., !^]ab%' 
       OR Doctor LIKE 'ms[., !^] _ ab%' 
       OR Doctor LIKE 'ab%')
```

Obviously this is quite a heavy query. We have an index on the `Doctor` column, but still this can take 3-5 seconds on large datasets which is a problem (we use this for auto complete while searching for a doctor's name).

Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: You really need to treat that as 2 separate questions, because each RDBMS has different ways to improve the performance. In the first instance, for SQL Server, we need an execution plan using "Paste The Plan".

Comment: "Is there any way to speed this up?" -- Yes, but the solution is different for SQL Server and for PostgreSQL.

Comment: We deploy for both. Should I delete this question and post two identical ones with different tags ?

Comment: We still need the execution plan though...

Comment: I would be tempted to create another column where all the prefixes have been removed and have an index on that so and then you don't need a series of OR statements to find it, and the index would be efficiently used.

Comment: Best to go as @Dijkgraaf said; but you can make it a computed column using the expression above; and index it (that materialises it).

Comment: If your intent is to search for last names starting with "ab", then it would be best to change your database design to store salutation, first, middle, and last name as separate columns. You could then filter for `LastName LIKE 'ab%'`, which the database engine can optimize, if an index on `LastName` is available.

Comment: Why not read in unique list of doctors in your application and then use that as source for auto completion. In my opinion, keyboard action shouldn't have to wait for db access

Answer (score 2):

Ideally.

1. Update your database design to split the salutation/prefix, first name and last name
2. Have a calculated column that starts with what you expect to search for (e.g. last name, first name) and have it convert it lower case (if your collation is not case insensitive). I've called it DoctorKey in the example below.
3. Have an index on this field

This way your like will as below, which will use an index effectively, as it knows what it starts with, so it can do a index seek and then index scan.

```
SELECT Doctor FROM Table WHERE DoctorKey LIKE 'ab%'
```

You can possibly do the calculated column without separate fields, but then you have to have a more complex calculated field, and there is more chance of the calculated column not calculating correctly.