# POSTGRES DISTINCT LIKE slow

Tags: postgresql

We have the following query on POSTGRES

```
SELECT DISTINCT Doctor 
FROM Table 
WHERE (LOWER(Doctor) SIMILAR TO 'dr[.,][ !^]ab%' 
       OR LOWER(Doctor) SIMILAR TO 'dr[., !^]ab%' 
       OR LOWER(Doctor) SIMILAR TO 'dr[., !^] _ ab%' 
       OR LOWER(Doctor) SIMILAR TO 'mr[.,][ !^]ab%' 
       OR LOWER(Doctor) SIMILAR TO 'mr[., !^]ab%' 
       OR LOWER(Doctor) SIMILAR TO 'mr[., !^] _ ab%' 
       OR LOWER(Doctor) SIMILAR TO 'ms[.,][ !^]ab%' 
       OR LOWER(Doctor) SIMILAR TO 'ms[., !^]ab%' 
       OR LOWER(Doctor) SIMILAR TO 'ms[., !^] _ ab%' 
       OR LOWER(Doctor) SIMILAR TO 'ab%')
```

Obviously this is quite a heavy query. We have an index on the Doctor field but still this can take 3-5 seconds on large datasets which is a problem (we use this for auto complete while searching for a doctor's name).

Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Can you pre-compute `Lower(Doctor)` with all these prefixes removed, then index and search on that column instead of doing this bunch of lookup prefixes?

Comment: @STerliakov unfortunately I can't. IT will mean writing scripts to update huge databases in many installations

Comment: What sort of index is on the (presumably text) field?

Comment: So, you can't run any database migrations and look only for ways to optimize the query, without modifying the underlying schema? It may not work at all, unfortunately.

Comment: Wait a minute...didn't you ask the same question for SQL Server a few minutes ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77998237/distinct-like-query-very-slow-even-with-index

Comment: Why lump title, appellation, and name together in a single column? Clean up your table design (and data) and this query will be simple and fast. Avoid non-sargable expressions on the filtered column. Oh, and *never* user `SIMILAR TO`. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684 For a serious performance question, please show your exact table definition, your version of Postgres, some sample values and explain why exactly you query like that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes I did and was told to post separate questions for SQL server and Postgres so I did

Comment: @kofifus Thanks for replying, and nothing inherently wrong with doing that.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter unfortunately changing the schema is not an option for my organization. There's a large installation base and migration etc is simply not feasable

Comment: @kofifus: ... which leads to the rest of my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appreciate that you can just use a single case-insensitive regex pattern [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NjLYew8A):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Doctor
FROM yourTable
WHERE Doctor ~* '^((dr|mr|ms)(([\.,][\s!^])|[\.,\s!^])(\s.\s)?)?ab';
```

This gets around having to do so many regex checks, and also eschews the need to lowercase the `Doctor` column.

Comment: @kofifus You could even try the extension pg_trgm and index this column. pg_trgm does support regexes. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-INDEX